# Use of pooling for my web App in servlet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, hikaricp

I'm using google app engine JAVA 8 and servlet 3.1 and would like to use HikariCP for pooling.

I'll write my logic in pseudo-code for better understanding.

At this point when user connects to a servlet it creates a new connection to database every time.

so my servlet looks a bit like this

```
doGet(){
  DatabaseObject db = new DatabaseObject()
  Connection conn = db.getConnection()
  db.createTable(conn)
  db.readData(conn)
  ...
  conn.close()
}
```

Now I've seen many pooling examples like [this one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet/src/main/java/com/example/cloudsql/ConnectionPoolContextListener.java)
but first I'm not sure this is what I'm trying to achieve also I don't really understand the whole process

Any examples, explanations are welcome as I've tried searching the net and couldn't find some for servlets. So maybe I'm thinking the wrong direction

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: I think I've found a solution I only need to go back in path of the google example ( [over there](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet/src/main/java/com/example/cloudsql/IndexServlet.java)). but anyway I can't find another way to find/initialize pool and use back in servlet apart than using servletContext. is there another way? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That example looks like it stores the pool in the app (servlet) context.

I've done it differently.  Usually I create a class, call it MyDb.  Then I add various methods to it to access data.  Within it there is a getConnection() method.

Internally, MyDb has its own connection pool.  getConnection() simply returns a connection from the pool.  The pool is initialized when the first MyDb is created.

Something like this (this is for app engine so no port is specified):

```
private static DataSource pool = null;

public MyDb( String dbhost, String dbdsn, String dbuid, String dbpwd )
{
    try
    {
        if( MyDb.pool == null )
        {
            String dbconn = null;
            String dbclassname = null;

            HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

            dbconn = "jdbc:google:mysql://" + dbhost + "/" + dbdsn;
            dbclassname = "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver";

            config.setJdbcUrl( dbconn );
            config.setUsername( dbuid );
            config.setPassword( dbpwd );

            MyDb.pool = new HikariDataSource( config );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            logger.error( e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    protected Connection getConnection() throws Exception
    {
        return pool.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what about if connection is lost or timed out what happens. Not sure to understand the logic. thanks in advance